# mysqli speed vs php speed?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

say if I have 10 tables. These tables are joined together on different conditions. Would it be better to go through all of these conditions with php and then execute what you end up with, or just pull all 10 tables and use the appropriate data. Which would be faster? Thanks.

Comment: mysql is designed to store and process large amounts of data, php isn't.

Comment: It depends. We cannot make performance estimates for you based on virtually no information. Generally, anything you can do in SQL you should do in SQL. Except if the query is too complex and would benefit from being broken down into several queries...

Comment: they are just being joined together nothing complicated

Comment: and counting some columns from the tables

Comment: `join` **is** a complicated operation itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what your doing, something PHP is going to be light speeds faster and other MySQL is going to be.  If there are going to be a lot of read/writes from the database I'd generally say MySQL is faster, but if you're doing anything with arrays of the data PHP is most likely going to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly doing it in mysql would be faster.  mysql is optimized for this kind of thing; php isn't.  And doing it in mysql avoids having to serialize all of the data to transfer it between the two processes.

Beware premature optimization, though.  Write it whatever way is easier and optimize later if its performance is a problem.